# Angular HTTP_INTERCEPTOR without change detection

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

In my app I have created a HTTP_INTERCEPTOR. It works, but the problem is that after completing the component is not detecting the changes.

Interceptor:

```
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
      ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const user = this.authenticationService.userValue;
    const isLoggedIn = user && user.token;
    const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(environment.apiUrl);
    if (isLoggedIn && isApiUrl) {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`
            }
        });
    }
    return next.handle(request)
)
```

Component function:

```
test() {
    const url_ = "https://localhost:44320/api/Plan/Get?start=2022-12-16&end=2023-01-16";
    this.http.request("post", url_, {}).subscribe(res => {
      this.employees = res;  // <-- Is not detected in view
    });
}
```

I have tried wrapping the interceptor return in NgZone.run() but this does not help. I have tried ApplicationRef.tick() in the intercepter, which also does not help.

It does however work if I use the ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() in the component, but it seems very cumbersome having to do this after each request in each component.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What changedetectionstrategy are you using in your component?

Comment: Default. All other change detection works as expected.

Comment: No wait. Actually it seems that the app.component had Push as changeDetectionStrategy which might have been the problem. Sorry I did not see that sooner... Thanks!